# How to list all unique elements in column B related to each unique element in column A?

Tags: r

[image]

I have a table with columns A and B and I want to list down all unique elements in column B related to each unique element in column A in R.

Comment: `aggregate(B~A, df, function(x) toString(unique(x)))`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I ran it however, it has been almost 2 hrs now and my code hasn't finished executing. Is this normal given that I have some 2,50,00,000 rows?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the function `aggregate`

Assuming the dataframe/datatable has the name `df`, you can use the code below:

```
aggregate(B~A, df, function(x) toString(unique(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I ran it however, it has been almost 2 hrs now and my code hasn't finished executing. Is this normal given that I have some 2,50,00,000 rows?

Comment: If you have 2 billion rows, it's not surprising that it takes a lot of time.